# What exactly is "BGP poisoning"?

Tags: routes, bgp

I found statements "BGP poisoning" and "poisoned AS" in several papers and sometimes it seems to refer to something that is done the achieve a certain thing sometimes it is considered something bad but it is never explained what exactly "BGP poisoning" actually is.

As I wasn't able to find an answer to this question myself I would appreciate if you could provide me your understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.03716.pdf has a description

Summary:

- Say router Rdst wants to influence the path that inbound traffic takes, say for example traffic from router Rsrc to router Rdst.
- Say the shortest path from Rsrc to Rdst goes through some intermediate router Rint.
- Let's say router Rdst in autonomous system ASdst, router Rsrc is autonomous system ASsrc, router Rint is in autonomous system ASint, etc. (see figure below)
- In particular, router Rdst wants to enforce that the traffic does *not* go through router Rint but instead takes some longer route, for example through some alternative routers Ralt1 and Ralt2 (once again, see figure below).
- To achieve this, router Rdst "poisons" its routes when it sends out BGP advertisements for its own destination prefix:

  - Instead of advertising the normal AS-path (ASdst), it instead advertises (ASdst, ASint, ASdst).
  - Note that Rdst is "lying": it claims that the path already went through ASint, when in fact it didn't.
  - It also adds an extra ASdst to make sure that the first AS in the AS-path still looks normal (= the AS of the advertising router).
  - When Rint receives the BGP UPDATE advertised by Rdst, it will see that there is a loop in the AS-path and treat the UPDATE as a withdraw. In particular, not propagate the advertisement to Rsrc.
  - On the other hand, the BGP advertisement will propagate normally from Rdst to Ralt1 to Ralt2 to Rsrc.
  - Hence, from the perspective of Rsrc, the only remaining feasible path is Rsrc -> Ralt2 -> Ralt1 -> Rdst.
- Ergo: Rdst has achieved its goal of forcing the traffic to avoid Rint.

```
          Rdst (ASdst)
     ____/    \_____
    /               \
Ralt1 (ASalt1)      Rint (ASint)
   |                 |
Ralr2 (ASalt2)       |
    \____       ____/
         \     /
          Rsrc (ASsrc)
```